# Como verificar se o login existe no banco por ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Fiz um sistema de login com ajax e php nele eu passo o login e a senha que estao no banco porem queria saber o que ha de errado com meu codigo pois sempre que tento logar no site com um login valido ele cai na minha condicao de falso e aparece que eu nao posso redirecionar. dei um alert no retorno do ajax que mostra o resultado da pagina php e esta correto quando eu digito os dados certos ele me traz em um alert que foi possivel conectar o que eu preciso fazer para meu ajax nao ficar caindo na condicao false do meu if?
obs nao vou postar o php pois testei somente em php e funcionou perfeito o problema esta no ajax

codigo:

```
$("#logar").click(function(){
          var email = $("#email").val(),
              senha = $("#senha").val();
          if(!senha){
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            $('#senha').tooltip('hide');
            $(".tooltip").show();
            $("#senha").focus();
            return;
          }

          $.ajax("../sys/logaradm.php",{
            type: "POST",
            data: {'usuario':email, 'senha':senha}
          }).done(function(r){
            alert(r);
            if(r==1){
            alertify.success("Acesso concedido redirecionando...");
            setTimeout("document.location = 'administracao.php'",2500);
          }else{
            alertify.error("Usúario ou senha informados nao existem!");
          }
          }).fail(function(){
            alertify.error("Ocorreu um erro durante a operacao!")
          }); 
      });
```

codigo php:

```
session_start();
    require "conexao.php";
    $usuario = trim(@$_POST['usuario']);

    $senha = trim(@$_POST['senha']);

    $sql_acesso = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM adm WHERE email = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha' ");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_acesso) == 1 ){

        $_SESSION['usuarioSession'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['logadoadm']= true;
        //$_SESSION['senhaSession'] = $senha;


            echo "
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Login efetuado com sucesso!\");
                    window.location='administracao.php';
                    </script>";
        }
        else{
            echo "
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Usuario ou senha informado esta incorreto!\");
                    window.location='../admin/admin.php';
                    </script>";
        }
        mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: Seu php retorna o que depois da consulta?

Comment: o que sai no alert(r)?

Comment: if ou o else se estiver certo ele retorna e redireciona para a pagina por exemplo podeacessar.php e no else ele volta pra mesma pagina naopodeacessar.php

Comment: no alert esta saindo o resultado do php do if e do else

Comment: sim, mais ele não imprimi primeiro o alert(r)?

Comment: tipo o erro e assim se eu logo certo no alert vai aparecer login efetuado com sucesso mas ai ele cai nesse else do ajax e nao  vai

Comment: sim intao ele imprimi isso que acabei de falar no alert login efetuado com sucesso

Comment: mais no if você compara `r == 1`, e o retorno do r `é login efetuado com sucesso`?

Comment: `r` tem qual valor? `1`, `0`, `undefined`  ?

Comment: depende se eu colocar os dados certo ele vai mostrar no alert login efetuado com sucesso se eu colocar os dados errado ele vai dar que o usuario nao existe NO ALERT ai nesse if teoricamente era pra ele comparar o resultado com verdade tipo se exister faca isso senao isso mas ele nao faz sempre cai no else desse if(r==1)

Comment: então você deve ter um retorno diferente pra comparar no IF. 1 para efetuado com sucesso e 0 para autenticação falha, ou algo do tipo

Comment: eu ja comparei com true tbm e sempre caiu no else mesmo colocando os valores coretos

Comment: intao mas nao e isso que estou fazendo estou comparando com 1 se existir vai pra tal pagina senao volta pra msm

Comment: rray o r e o retorno da funcao done do ajax

Comment: vou subir me codigo php pra ver se ajuda

Comment: pronto editei pra tentar deixa mais claro aqui quando eu digito tudo certo conforme o que esta cadastrado no banco de dados nesse alert(r) ele me retorna isso  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Login efetuado com sucesso!\");
                    window.location='administracao.php';
                    </script>";

Comment: e quando eu digito tudo errado ele me retorna isso no alert(r)         <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Usuario ou senha informado esta incorreto!\");
                    window.location='../admin/admin.php';
                    </script>";   porem mesmo se eu digitar tudo certo com o ajax ele me traz a condicao verdadeira do ajax mas a do php ele me traz o login efetuado com sucesso

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que a variáve `r` do javascript nunca tem o valor `1`, pois a saida de texto do php é uma string contendo javascript.

veja:

```
 echo "
     <script type=\"text/javascript\">
       alert(\"Login efetuado com sucesso!\");
       window.location='administracao.php';
       </script>";
 } else{
      echo "
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
       alert(\"Usuario ou senha informado esta incorreto!\");
       window.location='../admin/admin.php';
       </script>";
}
```

Faça o php retornar o número de registro retornados assim, agora `r` pode ter algum valor numerico como `0` ou `1`. No javascript(lado cliente) faça as validações, alerts e redirecionamentos.

```
$existe_registro = mysqli_num_rows($sql_acesso);
if($existe_registro == 1 ){
    $_SESSION['usuarioSession'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['logadoadm']= true;
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
echo $existe_registro;
```

Comment: perai to confuso nao intendi isso que voce falo pra mim faze no php nao e a mesma coisa que eu fiz?

Comment: @LeonardoCosta você está usando ajax para se comunicar com o php e para não escrever javascript dentro do php.

Comment: intao eu altero aquela minha linha por essa que voce fez

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, basicamente criei uma variável e removi os echos com javascript, só ficou aquele no final, o valor `$existe_registro` vai passar `r` no javascript.

Comment: mesmo assim cara continua com o erro

Comment: @LeonardoCosta qual erro? Quando vc faz `console.log(r)` o que é exibido?

Comment: vo ve guenta ai

Comment: nao ta recebendo nada vi pelo break point que o valor dele antes do alert e r=""

Comment: cara mas acho que isso nao tem nada haver por que ja usei o ajax assim varias vezes inclusive em um form de contato e ele vai de boa so aqui que ta assim

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, recomendo que coloque valores simuladores em `$usuario` e `$senha` e acessa o arquivo php pelo navegador e veja qual é saída. Se precisar troque o `echo $existe_registro;` por `var_dump($existe_registro)`

Comment: preenchi os campos e ta me retornando int(0)

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, zero significa que sua consulta não retornou nenhum registro

Comment: mas como que esse codigo nao ta retornando consulta sendo que uso ele pra fazer o login e testei sem o ajax e funcionou

Comment: do jeitinho certo caindo nas condicoes quando existia login e caindo na outra condicao quando nao existia

Comment: resolvi o erro eu apenas tinha que dar echo 1 no meu if em php e echo 0 no else ai ele comparava

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, esse era o objetivo de `$existe_registro` que era o número de linhas retornadas pela consulta.